# How to get data by $_GET on php, when i used .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

i have One problem on my small sites, the problem is on the URL. this is my URL :

`http://example.com/by_location_directory_list_3.aspx?page=2`

And on my PHP script, i want to show a data where it gets from `$_GET[page]`

i have do something, and something, no one works, any someone can help me?
this is `.HTACESS` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^by_location_directory_list_(.*)\.aspx$ template.php?option=directory_list&location=location&id=$1 [L]

Options All -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

the PHP script is

```
if(!empty($_GET['page'])){ echo "this on $_GET[page] page(s) "; }
```

Comment: Replace `[L]` with `[L,QSA]` for query string append.

Answer (score 1):

Use the QSA-tag, `Query String Append`: [QSA,L]

This will, if present, append the existing query string of the url to the redirected one.