# Get $_GET parameter from html file (php & htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently have 2 major pages (category & product) that handle almost everything on the site and these are converted from php to html files via htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?cid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ product.php?pid=$1
```

If you go to http://mysite.com/books, it will load category.php?cid=books

I want to add another paramater which is AID so when someone goes to http://mysite.com/books?aid=123, it actually loads category.php?cid=books&aid=123

Also the same for the product pages too.

I'm getting myself confused though on how i can do this via .htaccess.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need QueryStringAppend flag for the rewriterule. `[QSA]` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule

Comment: Would you guys please just google your problem our just use the so internal search, just yesterday i answered a similar question and many more are already around here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537536/how-to-get-data-by-get-on-php-when-i-used-htaccess/17537582#17537582

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the query string append ([`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule)) flag. It will preserve and append any query string paramaters to your rewrite.

For example, `/books?q1=123&q2=456` will redirect to `/category.php?cid=books&q1=123&q2=456`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?cid=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ product.php?pid=$1 [QSA]
```